# How do you show that sum of $1$ to $(n-1)$ is divisible by $n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

This is strange, I know I'm missing something important to understand, this proof can't be wrong. but when I see in the book that says (with proof) that: The sum of all natural numbers from $1$  to $(n-1)$ is always divisible by $n$, I get confused because the first example I tried, made it look false.

If $n=4$ than the sum $ {1...(n-1)} = 1+2+3 = 6$ which is not exactly divisible by $4$ (not in the whole numbers sense at least) .. what is wrong here?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: The sum of all numbers from $1$ to $n$ is $n(n+1)/2$, try and use this to figure it out.

Comment: i know this but what about the example i showed. is 6 divisible by 4?

Comment: $n=2$ is already a counterexample, as is every other even $n$.

Comment: u r right but the confusion arises from the fact that in the book i'm reading it doesn't say anything about n being an odd is necessary. should i assume that its authors fault?

Comment: @Asim: Yes, the book is simply wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You might know that for any $ n\ge 1$,

$$S_n=0+1+2+3+...+(n-1)=\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$$

hence $$ n|S_n \iff \frac{n-1}{2}\in \Bbb N$$

$$\iff n \text{ is odd}$$
this is not the case for $ n=4$.

Comment: so that means its only true for n as odd number?  but in the book it doesn't say about odd.

Comment: @Asim You gave the counterexample which proves the book is wrong.